# Is it possible to replace a word (before or after) a phrase based on condition using regular expression in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Input text: `Engineering School, Medical school, The School of Science, High School of science`

Output required: `[X] school, [X] school, The School of [X], High School of [X]`

Rule: any words before the phrase `school of` or (case insensitive) or School (case insensitive) needs to be replaced by `[X]`. But both rule should not execute at the same time.

```
$inputext = "Engineering School, Medical school, The School of Science"; 
$rule ="/\w+(?= school)/i";
$replacetext = "[X]";
$outputext = preg_replace($rule, $replacetext, $inputext);
echo($outputext);
```

To make it clear
 - the rule should be triggered based on occurrence of 'School of' and 'School' (both case insensitive). 
 - When 'School of' is present then the rule on 'School' should not be triggered

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What about: `High school of Science`?

Comment: I don't have a solution when both pattern occurs in the text.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/RcrNkq/3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will replace `school of ...` with `school of [X]` and `... school` with `[X] shool` unless followed by `of`

```
$inputext = "Queen's School, Engineering School, Medical school, The School of Science, High School of science the school is closed"; 
$rule = "/\b(?!the school is)(?:(?<=\bschool of )\S+|\S+(?= school\b(?! of)))/i";

$replacetext = "[X]";
$outputext = preg_replace($rule, $replacetext, $inputext);
echo $outputext,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
[X] School, [X] School, [X] school, The School of [X] High School of [X] the school is closed
```

Comment: @user4826347: >Just replace `\w` with `\S` (Not a space), see my edit.

Comment: For phrase, "the school is" i don't want the rule to be executed, is this possible add this condition to the above rule?

Comment: @user4826347: Does it work when you change `(?! of)` with `(?! of| is)` at the end of the regex?

Comment: more than the word 'is' afterwards it is the word before i.e. 'the' where i want to apply a condition

Comment: In principle if the expression can have an addendum to the structure where I can specify a word to be avoided (in this case 'the') before 'School', it would be exactly the one that I am looking for. The expression need not specify word after ('is' in this case) in the addendum.

Comment: @user4826347: replace `is` with `\w+`

Comment: That worked. $rule = "/\b(?!the school \w+)(?:(?<=\bschool of )\S+|\S+(?= school\b(?! of)))/i";

Comment: How can I add more conditions ? if it has to skip 'my school is', then  I tried $rule = "/\b(?(!the|!my) school \w+)(?:(?<=\bschool of )\S+|\S+(?= school\b(?! of)))/i"; but didn't work. I suppose i m wrong in the way I used or condition

Comment: @user4826347: `\b(?!(the|my|your|our|their) school \w+)`

Answer (score 0):

You may use this lookaround based regex for search:

```
.*\K(?>(?<=school of )\w+|\b\w++(?= school))
```

Replace it by:

```
[X]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Loton2/1)

**PHP Code:**

```
$re = '/.*\K(?>(?<=school of )\w+|\b\w++(?= school))/';
$repl = preg_replace($re, '[X]', $str);
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `.*\K`: Match 0 or more characters at the start and reset the match info
- `(?>`: Start atomic group

  - `(?<=school of )\w+`: Match a full word preceded by `"school of "`
  - `|`: OR
  - `\b\w++(?= school)`: Match a full word followed by `" school"`
- `)`: End atomic group

Comment: PHP is parsing your code. I might be wrong but I think this bit ?>(?< is causing parsing error.

Comment: Precisely I reckon ?> is the issue as it is closing syntax in the PHP

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. strangely it is not working for me!

Comment: As I suggested you can use `$re = '/.*\K(?:(?<=school of )\w+|\b\w++(?= school))/';` also. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes but with little success

Comment: Here is working code with above regex and sample data you provided: https://ideone.com/6bDQdj Now if something is not working for you then you need to provide your code for further assistance.